# Elementor! How to close a popup after a few seconds at the touch of a button I make

Tags: wordpress, popup, elementor

How to close a popup after a few seconds at the click of a spacial button ?

Comment: Do you have some code you tried to create?
Do you want to create this via elementor only, or with custom code? (the latter is what StackOverflow is largely there for)

Comment: I I think I need a code here
Because with the many options in Elementor it is still not enough for the specific result I want

Comment: Can you add the code (frontend) of the popup element?

Comment: the problem that in elemntor we dont have code... to halp us-designer-build sites easily. I can add class/id to the button. and thene I can add php function. https://elementor.com/help/how-to-trigger-a-popup-on-a-link-click/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Elementor has JS functions to close and open popups - you can use them with an "on click" function in jquery and a timeout.

Comment: so like `elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.closePopup( { id: yourPopupIdHere } );`

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to time delay close see:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
setTimeout(
   function(){
      document.querySelector('.dialog-close-button').click();
   }, 4000);
});
```

Possible repost of [Close Elementor Popup with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65676418/close-elementor-popup-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I have written it in the comments, by I will answer as well.

Elementor Pro has JS functions for the popups. So you can call it like this
`elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.closePopup( { id: yourPopupIdHere } );`

All together :

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( document ).on( 'click', '.close-popup', function( event ) {
        setTimeout(function() { 
            elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.closePopup( {id: yourPopupIdHere}, event )} );
        }, 4000);
      });
} );
```

Might have gotten som syntax wrong, but it should give you an idea